# Enabling CORS for Tomcat running in IntelliJ

Tags: angular, tomcat, intellij-idea, jersey, cors

I'm building an Angular project with a Jersey backend API. I'm running into an issue where my web app can't call the API running in debug mode using IntelliJ and Tomcat because of CORS. How can I access the CORS header options for the Tomcat instance running in IntelliJ.

Or is this not generally the pattern that SPA's use to talk with a backend? Is there a different way I should be building my project?

Comment: I've worked around this problem by having my backend support JSONP as well as JSON, and having my client code use the JSONP interface when it sees that it's running on localhost. I'd love to see a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get my Tomcat server running from inside of IntelliJ to accept CORS requests by adding the following to my web.xml file.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

IntelliJ yells at me and says it doesn't recognize that filter-class. But it compiles and runs perfectly. Also worth noting, you should definitely change the param value for allowed origins to be more restrictive in production. I'm allowing all origins here simply because I'm running locally.